# mysql_num_row returning 0 value from php function

Tags: php, mysql

i have this function in my script.php
$email=$_SESSION['cspa']['email'];

```
    function getit()
    {
      $get_pendingsupport=mysql_query("select
    cus.email,
    datetime,
    s.service_type,
    subject,
    support_id,
    status,
    u.urgency
    from tbl_client_support c
    inner join tbl_client_service s on c.service_id=s.service_id
    inner join customer_reg cus on c.customer_reg_id=cus.id
    inner join tbl_client_urgency u on c.urgency_id=u.urgency_id

    where status='open'
    and cus.email='$email';

    ") or  die(mysql_error());

     return mysql_num_rows($get_pendingsupport) ;
    }
 that my function and am calling it like this in home.php
```

but it returning 0 as the value 
but when i bring it to home.php it's okay
please what could be wrong

Comment: tanks so much it worked kind of enjoying this forum u rock

Answer (score 1):

It returns zero because zero rows are being returned. Why? Because you never pass `$email` to your function so it is not available to your query. Since it is used in your `WHERE` clause your query doesn't return the rows you think it does as no rows have a status of "Open" and an empty customer email field.

You can solve this by passing that variable to your function:

```
function getit($email)
{
```

and when you call it:

```
$num_rows = getit($email);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the $email to the query. Try this:

```
function getit($email)
    {
      $get_pendingsupport=mysql_query("select
    cus.email,
    datetime,
    s.service_type,
    subject,
    support_id,
    status,
    u.urgency
    from tbl_client_support c
    inner join tbl_client_service s on c.service_id=s.service_id
    inner join customer_reg cus on c.customer_reg_id=cus.id
    inner join tbl_client_urgency u on c.urgency_id=u.urgency_id

    where status='open'
    and cus.email='$email';

    ") or  die(mysql_error());

     return mysql_num_rows($get_pendingsupport) ;
    }
```